# getting on value on JSON the number iteration is repeating so many time .?

Tags: java

```
 String getQuesTemp(@PathVariable Integer questempId) throws JSONException{

        JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray jsonArray1=new JSONArray();
        List<QuestionaryVo> getQuesTemp;
        getQuesTemp = questionaryService.getQuesTemp(questempId);


        Iterator<QuestionaryVo> itr = getQuesTemp.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            QuestionaryVo quesTemp = itr.next();

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("questDesc_en",quesTemp.getQuestDesc_en());
            data.put("questType",quesTemp.getQuestType());
            data.put("mandatory",quesTemp.getMandatory());
            data.put("status",quesTemp.getStatus());
            data.put("controlMasterId",quesTemp.getControlMasterId());

            Iterator<answer>ite=quesTemp.getAnswers().iterator();
            while(ite.hasNext()){
                JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject();
                answer answ=ite.next();
                jsonObject1.put("answerValue",answ.getAnswerValue());
                jsonObject1.put("isCorrect",answ.getIsCorrect());
                jsonArray1.put(jsonObject1);
            }
            data.put("answers",jsonArray1);
            data.put("answersVo",quesTemp.getAnswersVo());


            jsonArray.put(data);
        }

        jsonObject.put("quesTemp",jsonArray);

        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
```

in this code, we had done double iteration process for this we getting output like this,

```
{,…}
quesTemp
:
[{questDesc_en: "question 1 about risk of the company", questType: 1, mandatory: 0, status: "1",…},…]
0
:
{questDesc_en: "question 1 about risk of the company", questType: 1, mandatory: 0, status: "1",…}
answers
:
[{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}, {answerValue: 3, isCorrect: 0}, {answerValue: 4, isCorrect: 0},…]
0
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
1
:
{answerValue: 3, isCorrect: 0}
2
:
{answerValue: 4, isCorrect: 0}
3
:
{answerValue: 1, isCorrect: 0}
4
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
5
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
6
:
{answerValue: 3, isCorrect: 0}
7
:
{answerValue: 4, isCorrect: 0}
8
:
{answerValue: 1, isCorrect: 0}
9
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
10
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
11
:
{answerValue: 3, isCorrect: 0}
12
:
{answerValue: 4, isCorrect: 0}
13
:
{answerValue: 1, isCorrect: 0}
14
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
15
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
16
:
{answerValue: 3, isCorrect: 0}
17
:
{answerValue: 4, isCorrect: 0}
18
:
{answerValue: 1, isCorrect: 0}
19
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
20
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
21
:
{answerValue: 3, isCorrect: 0}
22
:
{answerValue: 4, isCorrect: 0}
23
:
{answerValue: 1, isCorrect: 0}
24
:
{answerValue: 2, isCorrect: 0}
answersVo
:
["ddsg", "low", "moderate", "High"]
controlMasterId
:
"1"
mandatory
:
0
questDesc_en
:
"question 1 about risk of the company"
questType
:
1
status
:
"1"
```

excepted output is

this output needed for me
[
        {
            "questDesc_en": "question 1 about risk of the company",
            "questType": 1,
            "mandatory": 0,
            "status": "1",
            "controlMasterId": "1",
            "answers": [
                 {  "answerValue":2, "isCorrect":0}
            ],
            "answersVo": [
                "ddsg",
                "low",
                "moderate",
                "High"
                ]
        }
    ]

Comment: can you format the output so it displays the duplication more clearly?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I had multiple output but I need output in this format  [
        {
            "questDesc_en": "question 1 about risk of the company",
            "questType": 1,
            "mandatory": 0,
            "status": "1",
            "controlMasterId": "1",
            "answers": [
                 {  "answerValue":2, "isCorrect":0}
            ],
            "answersVo": [
                "ddsg",
                "low",
                "moderate",
                "High"         
                ]
        }
    ]

Comment: what do you mean multiple? please add actual and expected output to the question (NOT in comment)